# AWS S3 bucket AccessDenied when VPC is allowed

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have set up S3 bucket with the bucket policy like this:

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Id": "NginxProxy",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Sid": "AllowByVpc",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Principal": "*",
        "Action": "s3:*",
        "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::test/*",
        "Condition": {
            "StringEquals": {
                "aws:sourceVpc": "vpc-cf53cba8"
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "Sid": "DenyByVpc",
        "Effect": "Deny",
        "Principal": "*",
        "Action": "s3:*",
        "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::test/*",
        "Condition": {
            "NotIpAddress": {
                "aws:SourceIp": [
                    "185.24.222.124"
                ]
            },
            "StringNotEquals": {
                "aws:sourceVpc": "vpc-cf53cba8"
            }
        }
    }
]
```

}

and when I try command `curl -k -v --key client.key --cert client.crt -T abc.jpg http://test.s3.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/abc.jpg` on EC2 instance which is under the same VPC (vpc-cf53cba8) I get AccessDenied.

Unfortunatelly I don't know know what to focus on. Any idea?

Comment: Ok, but when I set public access, the curl request upload a file correctly. So?

Comment: Not sure what your question is. If you use curl, then you're making unauthenticated requests to S3 and public access would be required. If you want to limit access to a specific VPC then use authenticated access and a bucket policy with an allow condition on the sourceVpc (or a deny condition on not the sourceVpc).

Comment: But the previous bucket policy allows me to do that on the EC2 instance under the same vpc. I think "Principal": "*" means any unauthenticated access.

Comment: I think (but not 100% sure) that the issue here is that you are accessing S3 via the public Internet. This means that your S3 policy does not see anything about your AWS network. Add a VPC endpoint for S3. Then your EC2 instance will use the AWS private network to communicate with S3.

Comment: The Bucket policy won't accept that request because is not related to any VPC, it's just a request from a Client (like browser requests) rather than a request from an AWS service, SDK or CLIs.

Comment: Try to read the bucket with the CLI or SDK and you will be able to access the Bucket and its objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've resolved this by adding a VPC endpoint for S3 - https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-vpc-endpoint-for-amazon-s3/